# Why does this custom method of the DAO not work?

Tags: android, android-room, rx-java2

I ran across a problem when trying to insert an object into a sqlite database with the android room library.

I have the following dao:

```
@Dao
public abstract class ExerciseSetDao {
  public Completable insertExerciseSet(ExerciseSet set) {
    Completable completableSource = Completable.create(emitter -> {
      try {
        if(set.getRepRange() != null) {
          set.getRepRange().setOwnerExerciseSetId(set.getExerciseSetId());
        }

        _insertExerciseSet(set);

        emitter.onComplete();

      } catch (Exception e) {
        emitter.onError(e);
      }
    });

    return completableSource;
  }

  @Insert
  public abstract Completable _insertExerciseSet(ExerciseSet exerciseSet);
}
```

And in my view model I use it like this:

```
public void addExerciseSetButtonClick() {
  db.repRangeDao()
    .insertRepRange(repRangeForExerciseSet)
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
    .subscribe();

  exerciseSetToAdd.setRepRange(repRangeForExerciseSet);
  
  db.exerciseSetDao()
    .insertExerciseSet(exerciseSetToAdd)
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
    .subscribe();
}
```

Now the problem is when I check the database file I see that the `repRangeForExerciseSet` from the first command of the above method gets inserted perfectly fine but the `exerciseSetToAdd` doesn't get inserted into the database. BUT when i change the last line to the following (using the abstract method directly):

```
db.exerciseSetDao()
  ._insertExerciseSet(exerciseSetToAdd)
  .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
  .subscribe();
```

...the object gets added to the database too. But now my custom code in the `insertExerciseSet()` method doesn't get executed and I have no clue why it doesn't work the first way?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: just a thought, isn't it wise to keep the Dao limited to db operations and the logical code in a separate class, may be in ViewModel?!

Comment: Maybe it would make sense to create a separate class but in the ViewModel is not optimal as I need those methods in multiple ViewModels. Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I've found the problem.

When I call the abstract method `_insertExerciseSet(set);` it doesn't get executed because the return type is a Completable. So I have two options to make it work.

---

Calling the Completable with `.subscribe();` like this `_insertExerciseSet(set).subscribe();`

---

Or changing the return type for the abstract method `_insertExerciseSet` to void, because it already gets executed in an separate thread when it is called from the `insertExerciseSet` method.

```
  @Insert
  public abstract void _insertExerciseSet(ExerciseSet exerciseSet);
```